# SQLAlchemy set default value for postgres JSON column

Tags: python, json, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I want to set the default value of my SQLAlchemy postgres JSON column to an empty dictionary.

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSON

info = Column(JSON, default='{}')
info = Column(JSON, default={})
```

Neither of these work.

Comment: It's probably because the same `dict` instance is being used across *all* instances of your model. Try `default=lambda: {}`.

Comment: Thanks univerio that works. You can submit an answer and I can accept if you'd like. Otherwise I'll write my own answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using default=lambda: {} works. Credit goes to univerio in the comments.

Comment: More clean and concise solution, use it instead.

Comment: This no longer seems to work, have you been using the same solution?

Comment: @Konrad Yes I have. Maybe a newer version of SQLAlchemy broke this

Comment: Seems like it :'(

Comment: I use `default=dict` which is functionally equivalent to the lambda. This still works for me using SQLAlchemy 1.3.x

Comment: @ricekab that won't set the `server_default` though

Comment: @eli I've posted a new answer that sets `server_default` value too.

Comment: @eli It isn't supposed to work this way, though. Mnemonic: `default` - Python side, `server_default` - DB side.

Answer (score 12):

The easiest way I've found to define a JSON not null (if applies) column with a default `{}` value is (tested with SQLAlchemy 1.3.x):

```
info = db.Column(JSON, nullable=False, server_default='{}')
```

Comment: I did it without use `default`, used only `server_default='{}'`

Answer (score 7):

Just if someone struggles like me with `default` and `server_default` in combination with a `JSONB`-column, what seems to work is the following:

```py
from sqlalchemy import text

info = Column(JSONB, default=text("'{}'::jsonb"), server_default=text("'{}'::jsonb"))
```

The methods above (`default=dict` or `default=lambda: {}`) did **not** work for me. Especially in combination with alembic. I always got the error:
`sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Argument 'arg' is expected to be one of type '<class 'str'>' or '<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.elements.ClauseElement'>' or '<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.elements.TextClause'>', got '<class 'type'>'` (or `function` instead of `type` for the lambda).

Comment: Specifying `default` in alembic migration scripts is just meaningless - alembic never performs `INSERT`s or `UPDATE`s, and `default` is used only when there is no value for column _at_ `INSERT` or `UPDATE`. See: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/defaults.html.  As a rule of thumb, you should use only DDL-producing SQLA-constructs (like tables, columns) in your migration scripts.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. The answer was mainly for using it in a Python module, with SQLAlchemy as ORM where I experienced the problems (< v1.4). Btw, I'm also updating and inserting data using alembic, e. g. initial data or if data needs to be migrated, too. I've adjusted my alembic scripts so that e. g. the initial seeding data is coming from CSV-files or that I can upgrade/downgrade different "layers" of a database, from DDL, views or functions that are updated or just the data, where appropriate (as it is mostly bound to the tables and views of a certain revision).

Comment: FYI either `default` or `server_default` here works, and I didn't need to add `::jsonb` either. For anyone who has a non-empty default, here's an example: `privileges = db.Column(JSONB, nullable=False, default=text(f"'{json.dumps(default_privileges)}'"))` - where `default_privileges` is any `dict` defined for this purpose

Answer (score 5):

Better to use just `dict` constructor:

```
info = Column(JSON, default=dict)
```

Also, work perfectly for other types:

```
created = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
```

Comment: It is strange. Could you please share a gist with your model and an use case? Also take a look: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/defaults.html#python-executed-functions

Comment: It's been a long time ago. I will return with some sample code later @tosh

Comment: In the mean time, we have other who also cannot have default=dict working https://stackoverflow.com/a/60114072/248616